# How to return value from in FireReader Promesse

Tags: javascript, symfony, promise, fetch, filereader

I'm learning Javascript and i need a little help, my brain is broken.
My objectif is to parse my input (text and files) to JSON and send it with fetch API (for getting it on Symfony).

I use this javascript for translate the files to base64 and finaly JSON. It's works ! But ... i don't understand how i can return my jsonDataFile from my New FileReader to my body in my fetch API.

```html
<li><input type="file" id="file" name="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" multiple></li>
```

```js
      setFile_to_B64_to_JSON(){
        const files = this.files
        //return new Promise((jsonDataFile, jsonData) => {
        let formDataFile = new FormData();
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          const file = files[i];
          formDataFile.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            const base64String = reader.result
            .replace("data:", "")
            .replace(/^.+,/, "")
            let jsonDataFile = JSON.stringify(base64String)
            console.log(jsonDataFile)
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
          return jsonDataFile
        }
      }
```

```js
  async pushProject(){
    var buildjsoncontent = ''
    var buildjsonfile = ''
      buildjsoncontent = this.setProject();
      buildjsonfile = this.setFile_to_B64_to_JSON();

        let optionsFiles = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body:
            buildjsonfile
        }

      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/addimg', optionsFiles)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data1 => {
            console.log(data1)
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
   }
```

The methods setProject() is an another methods for send my input type text to JSON and it works.

If you have any idea or little tips, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why upload files as json? that is the worst. I would just append each file onto a formdata and upload all files as a application/multipart-formdata instead of reading the file content

Comment: I have already did that and it works ! But, if i want for X reason set an API in my project, i can juste use the same controller PHP in back then this for deal with the JSON response.